# BackboneJs: 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backboneJs and following the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSjvWtUxYk). I am creating a route for /users and doing the same as on tutorial but getting 404 not found whereas on tutorial its working perfectly.

**My Code:**

```
<script>

    var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: '/users'
    });

    var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function() {
            var users = new Users();
            users.fetch({
                success: function(users) {
                    var tempalte = _.tempalte($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models});
                    this.$el.html(template);
                }
            })
        }
    });

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home'
        }
    });

    var userList = new UserList();

    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:home', function() {
        userList.render();
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
</script>
```

**HTML Body**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1> User Manager </h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="page">

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
    <h1> Testing Template</h1>
</script>
```

and body also includes all other scripts. I am sure i am making a mistake but not able to find it. Please help, Thanks !!!

Comment: What URL are you getting 404 on? What is on the serverside listening for that URL? (Sorry, not inclined to watch the video tutorial.)

Comment: I am getting 404 on http://localhost:8888/users - "GET http://localhost:8888/users 404 (Not Found)"

Also, i have main index.html and i am writing the code in the same file at the moment. 

Why do we need server side listening when backbone js router is doing everything for us, No?

Comment: Not quite everything. If a user types a new location in the address bar, you will get a server request. If you change `document.location`, you will get a server request. It is only if you use `Backbone.history.navigate` that you get a backbone routing. You did not show how you end up at that URL.

Comment: Well at the moment this is all in one file i have -- Secondly my root folder is backbone in which i am this file(index.html) so i am accessing it like localhost:8888/backbone and i am expecting <h1> Testing Template</h1> which is working as per the tutorial. Now i am not sure why and how because all the steps before were working fine but only when i added the router to /users it showed error.

Comment: did you tried navigation to localhost:8888/index.html directly ? 
i think your error has nothing to do with backbone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code to the video is available here to compare:

[index.html](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/blob/gh-pages/videos/beginner/index.html)

I can see a few syntax errors in the posted code that are part of the problem. A variable "tempalte" is created but "template" is passed to $el.html(). There is also a ; missing after user.fetch({})

It should be like this:

```
users.fetch({
  success: function(users) {
    var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models});
    this.$el.html(template);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the mistake but it still did not work. I have not actually written the whole code of index.html link as i am following the tutorial and doing things step wise. So at the moment i am just rendering template with the same id and it should work but its still not. I tried copying your fixed code as well but failed. 

Do you see something else going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your getting a 404 when trying to fetch the users list. You need to change your collection to include the complete service URL:

```
var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com/users'
});
```

The other solution would be to use an ajaxPrefilter:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
});
```